# What is the best way to render the following ruby object tree in rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array(sorted on an attribute called node_id) of ruby objects which basically needs to rendered on the front end as a tree (ul > li> ul > li ...). I am using rails 2.3.8. This object is coming from the db, the structure of which might not be easily modifiable.

```
   [#<Node node_id: 3, children: "10, 42",name: "A", weight: 45, root: true>,
    #<Node node_id: 4, children: "6,88", name: "B", weight: 32, root: true]
    #<Node node_id: 6, children: nil, name: "X", weight: 12, root: false>,
    #<Node node_id: 7, children: "9", name: "P", weight: 98, root: true>,
    #<Node node_id: 9, children: nil, name: "Q", weight: 12, root: false>,
    #<Node node_id: 10, children: "23,56",name: "R", weight: 34, root: false>,
    #<Node node_id: 13, children: nil, name: "T", weight: 75, root: true>,
    #<Node node_id: 23, children: nil, name: "C", weight: 57, root: false>,
    #<Node node_id: 42, children: nil, name: "D", weight: 25, root: false>,
    #<Node node_id: 56, children: nil, name: "Y", weight: 50, root: false>
    #<Node node_id: 88, children: nil, name: "W", weight: 15, root: false>]
```

What is the best way performance and design wise to render such a tree at the front end? This is just a sample set, the tree is not always balanced and can have hundreds of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you convert children into an array of integers with the following

```
class Node
  def child_id_array
    case children
    when String: children.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
    when nil: []
    end
  end
end
```

Then, we can index the nodes (for constant time lookup) as follows:

```
index=Hash.new
nodes.each do |x|
  index[x.node_id] = x
end
```

Or if you have the `facets` gem installed, you can just say

```
index=nodes.group_by(&:node_id)
```

Let's find the root node(s) (the ones that arent a child of anybody else)

```
roots = index.keys - nodes.map(&:child_id_array).flatten
roots.uniq!
```

Now we render with a recursive function

```
def render allnodes, nodenumbers
  puts '<ul>'
  nodenumbers.each do |n|
    puts "<li>#{allnodes[n].name}" 
    render allnodes, allnodes[n].child_id_array
    puts "</li>"
  end
  puts '</ul'>
end
```

To kick things off

```
render index,roots
```

Comment: Nice, like the constant time lookup part. How do you think will it impact the performance if the render function is made non recursive?

Comment: There's no way to make render non-recursive and have it still work. It's basically performing what's called a depth-first search, and you need some kind of stack to backtrack . You could write a version that used a while loop, and maintained its own stack in an array, but I don't see the point. (Unless you're afraid of a stack overflow.)

Comment: I see your point. What do you think of shifting the recursion to an onload javascript snippet? I am afraid that the load time of this page with a hugely unbalanced graph could be an issue.

Comment: Try it this way first, and see if it's a problem. (I suspect the communication costs to do it in JavaScript will be higher than rendering on the server.) By the way, there's nothing about this algorithm that is affected by whether the tree is balanced or not. It's O(V) where V is the number of vertices in in the tree.

Comment: Cool thanks! Let me take this approach and test it out with different datasets.